# How to comma separate properties from a Laravel returned object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

First, my apologies if the issue has been resolved. I read a lot of similar posts, but not quite the right one for my case.
I am setting up a simple project in Laravel 5.8. I want to create a simple bookstore and I need a book to have multiple authors so each title is followed by the author, or authors - if many - separated by commas and the last one by the word 'and'.

I have set up two Models, 'Author' and 'Book' and their respective tables, as well as a pivot table since they are in a relation belongsToMany. Everything works like a charm, I get my results as expected. However, I cannot get to format the results as I need. In the case of multiple authors, I always get an extra comma in the end. Since I cannot get the commas right I haven't yet tried to add the last 'and' in the case of the last author.
In the case of a single author the solution is easy, I just use a conditional.
However in the case of multiple authors, thing get complicated.
The most popular method to similar problems was the use of implode() in various similar ways. The problem with this method is since Eloquent is using its internal logic to perform the query, when I loop through 'books', there is no author column, just a reference to the pivot table. In addition, the authors' include first name and last name in different columns. So, when I try to manually create an 'implodable()' array by fetching the respective data otherwise, I get double the item size, since each name consists of the first name and theist name. And on top of that, the whole thing runs inside a double loop, making things even more complicated for me. 
I am sure there is a simple way around this.

*This is a sample of my blade code as of now. Of course the conditionals should be rearranged accordingly when the problem will be solved, to implement the 'and' case:*

```
<ul>
      @foreach ($books as $book)
        <li>{{ $book->title }} by

            @if (count($book->author) == 1)  
              @foreach ($book->author as $name)
                {{ $name->last_name }}
                {{ $name->first_name }}
              @endforeach

            @else 

              @foreach ($book->author as $name)
                {{ $name->last_name }}
                {{ $name->first_name }}
```

{{-- print a comma here if there are other names, or an 'and' if it the last one. Problem seems that it needs to be solved outside the conditional, but how? --}}

```
              @endforeach
            @endif

          </li>
      @endforeach
</ul>
```

### My DB structure:

- 'authors': 'id', 'last_name', 'first_name','created_at', 'updated_at'
- 'books': 'id', 'title', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
- 'author_book': 'id', 'author_id', 'book_id','created_at', 'updated_at'

### Expected result:

1. Title 1, by Author 1
2. Title 2, by Author 1 and 2
3. Title 3, by Author 1, 2 and 3

### Actual Result:

1. Title 1, by Author 1
2. Title 2, by Author 1 and 2 and
3. Title 3, by Author 1 and 2 and 3 and

Comment: take a look at last()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't need the "and" mechanism, then `implode` with comma would do the job. For "and" mechanism use below code:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($books as $book)
      <li>{{ $book->title }} by
          @for ($i = 0; $i < count($book->author); $i++)
            {{ $book->author[$i]->last_name }}
            {{ $book->author[$i]->first_name }}
            @if ($i == count($book->author) - 2)
              &nbsp;and&nbsp;
            @endif
            @if ($i < count($book->author) - 2)
              ,&nbsp; 
            @endif
          @endfor
      </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

added non-breaking-space `&nbsp` wherever necessary to not get them linked to each other

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this solved the problem. Implode didn't work for me, I get an exception, invalid argument. Thank you so much anyway!

Comment: I think, the reason implode doesn't work in this case is because $book->author returns a collection, not an array...

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `@if (count($book->author) == 1)`, if you use foreach inside.
2. You can't use `@else`, when before you close condition with `@endif`.
3. This `@else` has wrong construction, use `@elseif` instead.
4. If you want check authors count and show extra value, do it inside foreach with `$book->author()->count()`.
5. What relation u have for book -> author? One book can have many authors or not?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I was still editing my post, so please check the latest code update. The relation is belongsToMany either way.

Answer (score 0):

Just display `implode(', ', $book->author)`, based on your actual result you don't need to do complicated checking if/else anymore.

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
        <li>{{ $book->title }} by {{print implode(', ', $book->author)}}</li>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer, however the implode method returns an exception 'ErrorException (E_ERROR)
implode(): Invalid arguments passed'